# Style Mui child component within parent component using CSS modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I am following [these docs](https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/#css-modules) in order to style a material ui component (Paper) within a component (Menu) I am using.

I am using CSS modules to style my components (with Webpack as a bundler) :

// menu.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
...
import styles from './styles.module.css';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';


const MyMenu = (props) => {
  ...
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <div id="my-menu">
        <Button id="button-react-component" onClick={handleClick}>
          My Menu
        </Button>
        <Menu
          id="menu-react-component"
          ...
          className={styles.menu}
        >
          <MenuItem ...>
            <span> Example 1 <span>
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
  );
}
```

// styles.module.css

```css
.menu {
  color: white;
}

.menu .MuiPaper-root {
  background-color: red
}

// Also tried : 
.menu .root {
  background-color: red
}
```

My goal is to have the `MuiPaper` component have a given background-color. `MuiPaper` is a component that comes from the `Menu` component, but I am not using `MuiPaper` directly as I am only declaring the parent (`<Menu>`).

Ideally I want to use `.css` files for styling. I use webpack to bundle my css files into modules.

Here's what I see in my browser :
[image]

[image]

Notice how the background-color "red" is not applied on that last screenshot.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

CSS modules can't override a style from another CSS module (or elsewhere). There's a few ways to get around this:

1. Add another class specifically for the `.menu` paper, e.g. `.menuPaper`, and add it via `PaperProps` on the `Menu` component:

```
.menuPaper {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```
<Menu
  id="menu-react-component"
  ...
  className={styles.menu}
  PaperProps={{ className: styles.menuPaper }}
>
```

2. Add the `:global` selector to your css selector:

```
.menu :global .MuiPaper-root {   
    background-color: red; 
}
```

CSS modules work by "modulifying" CSS classnames by adding a unique ID to the end of them. The `:global` selector can be used to disable this and preserve the classname instead.

The difference between these two methods is that if you had multiple Menu components in your `MyMenu` component, using the `:global` method would give all the `Menu` instances inside of `MyMenu`  the same background. With the `PaperProps` method only specific `Menu`s with `PaperProps={{ className: styles.menuPaper }}` would get the styles applied.

`css-loader`docs: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope

MUI `Menu` docs: https://mui.com/api/menu/#props (also see `Popover` component)

Comment: First, thanks for pointing this out :) Super helpful. Indeed, I was incorrect in my previous post, I just updated it. I realize now that what I want is to use is CSS modules here (not plain CSS). I'm still a bit unsure how to style `MuiPaper-root` which is a child element to my `<Menu>` here. Any guidance towards that would be appreciated :)

Comment: For example, according to the docs (https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/#deeper-elements-4) they use `.slider .MuiSlider-thumb` there.. I wonder why `.menu .MuiPaper-root` does not cut it here for my case.

Comment: @Rose It should be as simple as renaming your ```styles.css``` to ```styles.module.css```.

Comment: Good point. However, my file is indeed named `styles.module.css` and I import it as `import styles from './styles.module.css';` I've updated my code above to reflect that :) Forgot to copy paste that correctly when trying to provide a bit of a simpler example than what I had. I suspect my issue has something to do with my CSS selector, since I do see the class being applied on the Menu Element (color: white), just not the `MuiPaper-root` element (background-color: red) .

Comment: I've actually just tried : `.menu :global .MuiPaper-root {
  background-color: red;
}` and it did work. Wondering if this is a proper way to go about this though..

Comment: @Rose I see. CSS modules can't override a style from another CSS module (or elsewhere). Any style that gets defined in a module is "modulified" by adding a random id at the end of the classname, which gets applied when you import the style to your .js file. This does not happen however with the ```:global``` selector, only with local classes. I actually didn't realize you could put a local selector before ```:global``` like that for specificity, but it seems like intended behavior, so I'd say go for it!

Comment: Otherwise I would say "the MUI way" to do this would be to add another class specifically for the ```.menu``` paper, like ```.menuPaper```, and then add ```PaperProps={{ className: styles.menuPaper }}``` to the ```Menu``` component -

The difference here is that if you had multiple ```Menu``` components in your ```MyMenu``` component, using your ```:global``` method all the menus inside of ```MyMenu``` would have the same background, versus the MUI method, where only  specific ```Menu```s with ```PaperProps={{ className: styles.menuPaper }}``` would get the styles applied.

Comment: Thanks for proposing an alternative, I appreciate it. That last solution did not work for me unfortunately (not exactly sure why though). the `.menu :global .MuiPaper-root` was the only thing that did apply the color.  I did google a bunch to find examples but I see a lot of them using `makeStyles`, which seem to be deprecated at this point.